# Binding textBoxes in ASP.Net with variables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tried to bind together html input textBox

```
<input type="text" id="serviceName" value="@serviceName" />
```

with variable on the top of my cshtml file

```
var serviceName = Request.Form["serviceName"];
```

But when I set breakpoint on sql command where should serviceName have value it is still null.

May I know how to bind text in textBox serviceName to that variable?

Thank you for your time.

```
@{

Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
Page.Title = "Registrovaní uživatelé";





var serviceLat = Request.Form["serviceLat"];
var serviceLon = Request.Form["serviceLon"];
var serviceContact = Request.Form["serviceContact"];
var serviceDescription = Request.Form["serviceDescription"];
var serviceCrypto = Request.Form["serviceCrypto"];
var serviceLink = Request.Form["serviceLink"];
var serviceType = Request.Form["serviceType"];
var fileName = "";
var fileMime = "";
var serviceName = "";
var email = "";


var userId = Request.Form["userId"]; 
if (IsPost)
{
    var uploadedFile = Request.Files[0]; // on this line it fails
    fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
    if (fileName != String.Empty)
    {
        fileMime = uploadedFile.ContentType;
        var fileStream = uploadedFile.InputStream;
        var fileLength = uploadedFile.ContentLength;
        email = Request.Form["email"];
        serviceName = Request.Form["serviceName"];
        byte[] fileContent = new byte[fileLength];
        fileStream.Read(fileContent, 0, fileLength);
        var db1 = Database.Open("StarterSite");
        var sql = "UPDATE services SET FileName=@0, FileContent=@1, MimeType=@2,"+
           "IDTypeOfService=@4,IDCryptoCur=@5,GeoLong=@6,GeoLat=@7,DescriptionService=@8,LinkService=@9,TitleService=@10,ServiceContact=@11 " + "WHERE IDklient=@3; IF @@ROWCOUNT=0 INSERT INTO services " +
        "(IDklient,IDTypeOfService,IDCryptoCur,GeoLong,GeoLat,DescriptionService,LinkService,TitleService,ServiceContact,FileName,FileContent,MimeType)"+
        "values (@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9,@10,@11,@0,@1,@2)";
       db1.Execute(sql, fileName, fileContent, fileMime, userId,serviceType,serviceCrypto,serviceLon,serviceLat,serviceDescription,serviceLink,serviceName,email);

    }
}
```

This is on the top of my page now html part:

```
  <section class="email">
        <form method="post">
<fieldset>
       <legend>Bez registrace</legend>
            <label for="email" @if(!ModelState.IsValidField("email")){<text>class="error-label"</text>}>Email address</label>
            <input type="text" id="emailFast" name="emailFast" value="@email" @Validation.For("email") />
            @* Write any email validation errors to the page *@
            @Html.ValidationMessage("email")
      <label for="email" >Název</label>
      <input type="text" id="serviceName" value=@Request.Form["serviceName"] />
      <label for="email" >Zeměpisná šířka</label>
      <input type="text" id="serviceLat" value="serviceLat"/>
      <label for="email" >Zeměpisná délka</label>
      <input type="text" id="serviceLon" value="serviceLon"/>
      <label for="email" >Kategorie</label>
      <input type="text" id="serviceType" value="serviceType"/>
      <label for="email" >Kontakt</label>
      <input type="text" id="serviceContact" value="serviceContact" />
      <label for="email" >Stručný popis</label>
      <input type="text" id="serviceDescription" value="serviceDescription" />
      <label for="email" >Krypto měna</label>
      <input type="text" id="serviceCrypto" value="serviceCrypto" />
      <label for="email" >Webová stránka</label>
      <input type="text" id="serviceLink" value="serviceLink" />
      <label for="email" >Logo</label>
     </fieldset>
```

```
         @FileUpload.GetHtml(
            initialNumberOfFiles: 1,
            allowMoreFilesToBeAdded: false,
            includeFormTag: true,
            uploadText: "Upload")


        @if (IsPost && fileName != String.Empty)
        {
            <span>Obrázek byl nahrán!</span>

        }
```

Still when I do the debug with breakpoint value for `serviceName` is null I still have problems with binding it.

Edit of the correct solution by Dylan Corriveau:

```
    <form method="post" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
```

[This](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp) sites says that it is neccessery to use this type of encoding if you are uploading a file.

Comment: I want to confirm something. Are your other variables null too? Or is it just the serviceName?

Comment: <input type="text" id="serviceName" value=@Request.Form["serviceName"] /> should be just value="serviceName". Right here, its saying "give me the value of serviceName, and place it in the value of serviceName", which doesn't exist, so it would be null

Comment: Other except the fileName, FileMime and every that is connected with uploading image. But the ones that should upload text from  textboxes are null.

Comment: try adding a name to each, as I said in my new edit. You should be able to just copy and paste it. Let me know what happens

Comment: @DylanCorriveau I tried it just with serviceName but still null. I quiet don't get it. It is in IsPost it has a name binded to variable. Where can be the problem? By the way I think if the value="serviceName" is inserted that it only sets the default text of the textbox right?

Comment: correct. That would only set the default value of the text box. hmmm.... so it works for ones like email, but it just doesn't work for the service name... right?

Comment: No no, the e-mail doesn't work either. It just works for uploading the file - fileName, fileMime, fileContent has values. But when I tried to add the textboxes like serviceName or email those  doesn't have the value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41778/discussion-between-dylan-corriveau-and-marek)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, I believe Request.Form takes in the Name of an input, not an ID. So in this case, it would be this:

```
var serviceName = Request.Form["@serviceName"];
```

If this isn't the issue, I would like to know a bit more information... Are you using MVC? WebForms? How are you sending your form over?

Edit:
I'm silly. @serviceName is the value you listed right? You would need to put a name element. Example. In your input, try this

```
<input type="text" name="serviceName" value="@serviceName" />
```

Then in your code, just do it like you had it before

```
var serviceName = Request.Form["serviceName"];
```

As I mentioned, each input should also have a name (you should be able to just copy and past that....)

```
  <label for="email" >Název</label>
  <input type="text" id="serviceName" name="serviceName" value="serviceName" />
  <label for="email" >Zeměpisná šířka</label>
  <input type="text" id="serviceLat" name="serviceLat" value="serviceLat"/>
  <label for="email" >Zeměpisná délka</label>
  <input type="text" id="serviceLon" name="serviceLon"  value="serviceLon"/>
  <label for="email" >Kategorie</label>
  <input type="text" id="serviceType" name="serviceType"  value="serviceType"/>
  <label for="email" >Kontakt</label>
  <input type="text" id="serviceContact" name="serviceContact"  value="serviceContact" />
  <label for="email" >Stručný popis</label>
  <input type="text" id="serviceDescription" name="serviceDescription"  value="serviceDescription" />
  <label for="email" >Krypto měna</label>
  <input type="text" id="serviceCrypto" name="serviceCrypto"  value="serviceCrypto" />
  <label for="email" >Webová stránka</label>
  <input type="text" id="serviceLink" name="serviceLink"  value="serviceLink" />
  <label for="email" >Logo</label>
```

Comment: thank you for your interest in helping me. I'm using Razor v2. But I'm not sure whether I use WebForms or not.  When I click in Visual Studio 2012 File - New - Website - Installed - Templates - Visual c# I choose ASP.NET Web Site (Razor v2) it is some kind of template from Microsoft. So that is what I choosen.

Comment: I'm guessing you tried the name i mentioned above? Also, not a problem! Also, a way to tell, do you have a controllers folder in your project? If so, that's probably MVC, if not, its WebForms

Comment: I tried `@serviceName` but the variable is still null. Well there isn't located any folder called `controllers` in the project solution. I have only: Account,App_Code,App_Data,bin,Content,packages,Scripts folders.

Comment: try my edit, also, that file structure sounds like WebForms as a general note. If you do get more questions in the future, try including that tag as well

Comment: thank you for your time but still it haven't changed anything. Can you please see the code edited in my question? Thank you so much.